# Abstract class for matrices

Tags: python, oop, matrix, abstract-class, physics

I'm trying to write and implement an abstract class for matrices in Python, with the intention of making some sparse matrix classes. I'm trying to translate some code from C#, which I can link if necessary. I don't really understand how to construct an implementation of the class, specifically how the enumerate function is supposed to work. I'm not really used to OOP, but I'm learning on the job!

The abstract class is:

```
class MatrixElement(object):
   def __init__(self, i, j, val):
       self.i = i
       self.j = j
       self.val = val
```

```
class Matrix(ABC): 
    
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.dimension = n

    @abstractmethod
    def get_value(self, i, j):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def set_value(self):
        pass

    def enumerator(self):
        for i in range(0, dimension):
            for j in range(0, dimension):
                yield MatrixElement(i,j, get_value(i,j))
    
    @abstractmethod
    def multiply(self, m):
        pass
    
    def __mul__(a, b):
        return a.multiply(b)

    def apply(self, v):
        assert(dimension == v.dimension, "Incompatible dimensions")
        u = Vector(dimension)
        for MatrixElement(me) in self:
            u[me.i] += me.value * v[me.j]
        return u
```

And I've begun to try make an explicit matrix, but I'm quite confused. I haven't populated the class because I'm not really sure how to get started:

```
class explicit(Matrix):

    def __init__(self, n):
        self = Matrix(n)
    def enumerator():

    def get_value(self, i,j):
        return  
    def set_value(i, j):
```

Comment: The method or we should now call it a generator `enumerator` in your class `MatrixElement` just keeps yielding each of the elements of the matrix one by one.

Comment: I've edited to make it a bit clearer, enumerator should be in the `Matrix` class and is supposed to index the matrix. I'm not really sure how to implement this in the explicit case.

Comment: Sorry for the typo I meant `Matrix` instead of `MatrixElement`, anyway as I said enumerator does nothing except enumerate over the elements. In fact from what I see you don't need to override it and it should work considering it would simply use `get_value`